# Problem configuring Sitefinity CMS with Active Directory

Tags: sitefinity

I'm able to configure Sitefinity CMS for use with ActiveDirectory for administrative logins following [instructions](http://www.sitefinity.com/devnet/kb/sitefinity-3-x/working-with-multiple-membership-and-role-providers.aspx) found on the Sitefinity knowledgebase.  This is what I have for a configuration:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="IowaDomain" connectionString="LDAP://iowa.uiowa.edu" />
</connectionStrings>
....
<roleManager enabled="true" cacheRolesInCookie="true" defaultProvider="Sitefinity">
    <providers>
        <clear />
        <add connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" applicationName="/" name="Public" type="Telerik.DataAccess.AspnetProviders.TelerikRoleProvider, Telerik.DataAccess" />
        <add name="Sitefinity"
             type="Telerik.Security.ActiveDirectory.TelerikADRoleProvider, Telerik.Security"
             connectionStringName="IowaDomain" 
             connectionUsername="******" 
             connectionPassword="******" 
             groupMaps="ITS-CTS-Sitefinity-Admins"
             domainName="iowa.uiowa.edu" 
       />
    </providers>
</roleManager>
<membership defaultProvider="Sitefinity" userIsOnlineTimeWindow="15" hashAlgorithmType="">
    <providers>
        <clear />
        <add name="Public"
             connectionStringName="DefaultConnection"
             type="Telerik.DataAccess.AspnetProviders.TelerikMembershipProvider, Telerik.DataAccess" enablePasswordRetrieval="false"
             enablePasswordReset="true"
             requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false"
             applicationName="/"
             requiresUniqueEmail="false"
             passwordFormat="Hashed"
             maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5"
             passwordAttemptWindow="10"
             passwordStrengthRegularExpression=""
             minRequiredPasswordLength="1"
             minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" />
        <add name="Sitefinity" 
             type="Telerik.Security.ActiveDirectory.TelerikADMembershipProvider, Telerik.Security" 
             connectionStringName="IowaDomain"
             enableSearchMethods="true"
             attributeMapUsername="sAMAccountName"
             connectionUsername="******"
             connectionPassword="******" />
    </providers>
</membership>
```

The configuration appears correct (and if I replace that provider with a dummy provider that simply logs calls and returns correct data I can see that the provider's methods are being called), but after logging in all requests time out.  I can see that the timed out request is correctly authenticated -- it appears in the event log as authenticated with the proper credentials -- but no request ever comes back.

Looking through the Sitefinity forums and around via Google I don't see any issues of this type reported.

FYI - I have also verified that I can connect to the DB using the supplied credentials for it (which I've omitted above).

**EDIT**:  Update -- same problem if I disable the Public providers.  The Sitefinity providers are still the default.

Any ideas?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about configuration/administration of a web application.

Comment: Good lord, if you've never worked with a CMS, you probably shouldn't be involved in migrating developer questions about them.

Comment: We've changed a lot in scope since 2010, unfortunately, so this is no longer on-topic if it ever was.  I don't see any record of this being migrated from SO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting the **httpRuntime** parameter *executionTimeout* to a larger value (600) seems to have solved the timeout issue.  Now I need to figure out why it's taking so long.